# return value to the function from outside

Tags: javascript

I'm comparing couple info and than try to get the correct object.
But I cant return the output to the function it self.

```
    channelUserRight: function(channel, nickname){

        userlist.forEach(function(chaninfo) {
            if(chaninfo.channel === channel && chaninfo.name === nickname){
                // Whenever I do console.log it shows me output
                console.log(chaninfo);
                return chaninfo;
            }           
        }); 

    }
// Here it shows me 'undefined'
console.log(channelUserRight(channel, user))
channelUserRight(channel, user)
```

So inside the function I get the correct object but not outside the function.

Comment: Your `channelUserRight` isn't returning anything.  Your `return` statement is *inside* the `forEach` callback.  That doesn't do anything.  The `forEach` callback runs for each element and any return values are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just return to the callback for the `forEach` function, if you use filter instead, you can return the filtered array, or just the first index directly

```
channelUserRight: function(channel, nickname){
    var list = userlist.filter(function(chaninfo) {
        return chaninfo.channel === channel && chaninfo.name === nickname;
    });

    return list.length ? list.shift() : null;
}
```

Comment: Kudos for the `.filter()` call.

Comment: How can I return it directly as [0] index else I need to edit to many code ?

Comment: @J.Doe - edited to return just the first index, if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you need to set a variable at the function level and use that to return your value:

```
function(channel, nickname){
  var _chaninfo;

  userlist.forEach(function(chaninfo) {
     if(chaninfo.channel === channel && chaninfo.name === nickname) {
        _chaninfo = chaninfo;
     }
  }); 

  return _chaninfo;
}
```

The problem is that `return` returns from the function block used to iterate. @adeneo's approach with `filter` is actually cleaner, so I'd recommend using that, but this is a "fix" for your immediate issue.